# How enable ClearType render with subpixel antialiasing on VSCode on Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cleartype

I'm working with VsCode but i noticed that ClearType was not applied on its fonts.

My windows settings has "cleartype" turned on.

Check the comparison.
[image]

How can I enable Cleartype render with subpixel antialiasing on VS Code ?

Answer (score 2):

As part of [November 2019 (version 1.41) Update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_improved-font-rendering-windows-linux), Visual Studio Code now has Improved font rendering (Windows, Linux) using ClearType render with subpixel antialiasing Technology.

> In this release, we improved font rendering in more parts of the workbench (for Windows and Linux). The screenshots below show a before and after comparison (zoomed in to show the difference). In particular, many tree and list elements of the workbench were rendered using greyscale antialiasing and they now render with subpixel antialiasing.

[image: Vs Code Cleartype render with subpixel antialiasing]